Do branch points and their indexes determine the branched covering of an algebraic curve?
Let $X$ be an algebraic curve over an algebraically closed field, and $Y$, $Y'$ be its branched covers. Suppose that $Y$ and $Y'$ have the same branch points over X and the ramification indexes of each branch point are equal, then can we deduce that $Y$ and $Y'$ are isomorphic?

No. For instance, if you look for a double covering with branch divisor $B \subset X$ then it is determined by a line bundle $L$ on $X$ and an isomorphism
$$
L^{\otimes 2} \cong \mathcal{O}_X(-B).
$$
But such a line bundle is determined by $B$ only up to 2-torsion in $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$. So, as soon as $g(X) > 0$, the covering is not unique.
